# How to Record a sequence of events in a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I want to create UNDO and REDO for my application.

this is the UNDO REDO class

```
 const int MAX_NUMBER_OF_UNDO = 8;

class UNDO_REDO
{
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Sum_UndoRedo>> undo;
    int currentNumber;
public:
    UNDO_REDO();
    void AddUndo(std::unique_ptr<Sum_UndoRedo>);
    void Pop_Back_Undo();
};
```

Every time a action is performed it is stored in the undo vector.

i want to record the last 8 actions , when the size of undo vector  increases more than 8  i erase the first element of the vector and than push back the action to the vector and always maintain the size of the vector as 8 which are the last 8 actions performed.

Since i have never done UNDO and REDO before  , is this a good way to do UNDO and REDO ?

Since Erase will move all the vector elements each time i perform erase do i have any alternative method to keep the size as 8 ?

Comment: If you are erasing from the front and adding to the back a `std::deque` would be a better structure.

Comment: Are you looking for [std::deque](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)?

Comment: BTW: you shouldn't use all capital identifiers, `UNDO_REDO` -> `Undo_Redo` for example.

Comment: how about using stack instead of vector? when you perform the operation push onto the stack; to undo the last operation just pop that operation from the stack.

Comment: If you don't want to keep an undo-redo tree like vim does, a stack would be the correct solution, as you only ever need the last element. Any time your code only uses `pop` and `push`, really.